# Grounding in a DC circuit on a vehicle

Tags: ground, safety, fuses, chassis

I am working on a vehicle with batteries, but i am not quite sure if my grounding solution/design is correct. It is supplied with two 12VDC batteries in series, connected to a DC-DC (24VDC-24VDC) powersupply. Basically i always ground the `0V` to the chassis, and use a 2-pole MCB after the batteries and 1-pole to devices. Is this a bad design?

[image]

Comment: Are the two 12V batteries used for anything else i.e. do they need to be grounded? Does any circuit need to be grounded? If so, why? Playing devils advocate!!

Comment: @Andyaka, i see i was fairly too quick with the schematic. There is actually devices connected after the `F1` MCB, which is protected with 1-pole MCB's, besides T1.

Comment: Do these need to be grounded and does the output of the 24V dc-dc need to be grounded?

Comment: @Andyaka, thats my actual concern. Im not certain whether its necessary or not in my case.

Comment: Basically don't ground stuff that doesn't need to be grounded. I suspect the motors are fed from the 12v+12v and these might inevitably be grounded and cause ground currents that are many, many amps - keep non essential stuff ungrounded would be my philosophy.

Comment: If the plc has sensors that are ground referenced then use differential inputs to measure the sensors etc..

Comment: @Andyaka, theres no fancy I/O's except digital ones. Basically there is a motorcontroller connected after `F1` which is protected with a 1-pole MCB.

Comment: Then let the "plc" communicate with the motor controller and have the only ground for the "plc" and "PSU" stuff be connected to the controller for digital signalling reasons. Do not let the chassis carry any signals either digital or analogue if there's half a chance that the motors are connected to chassis.

Comment: @Andyaka, but there won't be any problems in making the 0V common?

Comment: If you can avoid making the 0V common (across the dc-to-dc converter) this reduces the risk of another path carrying motor current getting into your control electronics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9459/discussion-between-javacake-and-andy-aka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your diagram and added two circles and a few lines: -

[image]

Firstly, the motors at the bottom - I don't think you should label the two wires to each motor as 24V and 0V - they are likely to be PWM outputs from the controller that form a H bridge and, if i'm correct there will be no current to ground or real 0V. I say no-current but the chassis will pick-up all sorts of interference from the heavy current fed to the motors and avoiding the chassis is best policy other than for a single connction (if necessary).

I've also drawn a circle around the controller and plc to indicate that there will likely be some control lines between the two or else how are you going to regulate motor speed? The type of connection needs establishing i.e. is it differential signalling? Do the signals share a local 0V? Can it be opto-coupled (least likely to give problems)?

When it comes to wiring, you have shown a bus type arrangement and this is OK for a circuit but you have to feed the 24V batteries (via over-current protection) directly to the controller. You can tee-off the lighter loads (dc-to-dc converter) directly from the battery. This means you have to star-point two 24V and two 0V conections at your battery terminals to avoid motor current giving problems to the converter etc..

Keep the wires from the battery to the motor controller as short as possible is a must.

You also, on your circuit have two over-current devices in the path from your battery to motor controller - I would avoid this - use F3 directly for the motor controller and I believe F4 is kind of redundant because it is protected by F2 in front of the dc-to-dc convertor. F1 I think would be redundant but if you have other circuits (not shown) then use an adequately rated device for those circuits.

Comment: 1) As you mention there will ofcourse be a H-bridge, so the labels are completely wrong. 2) Communication to motorcontroller will be through RS232 from a PC. 3) The purpose of the F1 was to have a main-breaker and overcurrent protection to the batteries, maybe this should be changed to a normal circuitbreaker instead of over-current protection? 4) I understand that i should feed F3 directly from the battery. 5) The purpose of F4 is because the PLC requires 3A fuse, while F2 is much larger. F2 was to protect the DC-DC converter.

Comment: @JavaCake  The RS232 might give the odd glitch - if you could use an RS232 isolator this would be less troublesome when operational I believe BUT, like i say it's down to avoiding the pesky chassis currents that inevitably will be there due to induction, possibly from motors and / or motor wiring.

Comment: the PC will be supplied from a PSU connected to the battery aswell, would this still cause a problem?

Comment: Do you have any input on my comment concerning the circuit breakers?

Comment: I have to mention that the motherboard of the PC and motorcontroller is attached directly to the chassis, this could cause grounding unless i use plastic washers.

Comment: @JavaCake regards the pc, see how it goes with it earthing on the chassis but if you get unexpected glitches there's a possibility it is that. On the breakers, too many aint gonna be a problem!!

Comment: if we ignore redundancy, do you see any critical error in the current design? Also in means of protection and overcurrent.. Ofcourse this requires that i write the wire gauges and device consumption, but just from an overview.

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause a fire or meltdown. In fact there's a fair chance it'll work glitch-free but be prepared to mess with gnd/chassis/0V points and isolation (maybe) on the 232.

Comment: i have 5 serial communications in the system all supplied from the PC. If i chose to skip isolation, which could end up being a little pricey, would i then be forced GND my 0V potential? Ofcourse only incase a problem would occur.

Comment: Yes your 232 port on the PC will have to have 0V grounded but, if that's the only ground it has then rogue chassis/motor currents are unlikely to be a problem but, if you then plugged in some other peripheral to the pc that made a 2nd ground connection you might find you get comms errors or the occasional pc crash due to circulating rogue current.

Comment: I have just been looking through the datasheet of my motorcontroller, and it has two GND connections in the communication port, which also consist of I/O's. When reading in the note they write `Note 5: Beware not to create a path from the ground pins on the I/O connector and the battery’s minus terminal.`

Comment: I assume that i need to GND the RS232 GND from the PC to the GND in the I/O.

Comment: That comms 0V/GND should ideally be the only 0V connection to the PC's 232 port and realistically it also means that any other 0V on the motherboard should be isolated from the general 0V/chassis end of the controller. This is the reason why I suggested breaking the 0V link across the dc-to-dc converter.

Comment: It just stroke me. If i do not have one of the legs grounded, will a 1-pole MCB still be valid?

Comment: @JavaCake it's breaking on over-current you are trying to achieve - it will work in either limb of the circuit. You don't need to switch both out for operational purposes or fire risk as far as I can see. Maybe you've got some spec to work to that says otherwise?

Comment: I read it in some literature way back, but something tells me it was in 125VDC+ systems.

Comment: @JavaCake you need to check this but my suspicion and gut-feeling is that it isn't required for safety on a low voltage circuit despite the high currents that can exist.

Comment: I will try to search for it again to verify it. Meanwhile i have created an additional question concerning MCB and fusing, if you have a input in this area feel free to toss in a comment.

Comment: @JavaCake do you have a link to the question?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75241/choosing-fuses-or-mcb-in-24vdc-vehicle-circuit

Comment: there was one particular thing that crossed my mind with my circuit. It does not seem right that i dont have 2-pole CB in the entire system if i dont ground my 0V? Is my system not a typical floating setup?

Comment: @JavaCake you can ground your 0V but this is best done in one place only. Given that your motor controller and anything else you hook-up may make a ground connection it's best to make this decision when set up to run to see if there are any anomalies when doing this. Not having it grounded at all doesn't seem an issue to me - after all the 0V end cannot pass any current if the CB on the power end is disconnected.

Comment: actually i am getting some checksum errors with the RS-422 bus at the moment.

Comment: @JavaCake Why don't you begin a new question relating to the RS422 - this was never mentioned in the original and this seems like a new episode. Please also post a schematic of what you've got and where earths and 0Vs are etc..